# reading buffered text data to string

Tags: c++, string, file, stl

Hi I want read from a hung text file data directly to a string 
I know that i can use the following:

```
ifstream infile("myfile");
string str(istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

but this way read whole file in one step.
I want read it in several step beacuse this is very larg file about 50GB.
How I can do it?
thanks for your advice Herzl.

Comment: But you do want the entire file in a string?

Comment: not whole file in once. each time I want to read 1MB data.Process it then read remiand data from file.

Comment: It's duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540183/how-can-i-read-exactly-128-bytes-from-an-fstream-into-a-string-object).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading directly from an std::istream into an std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816319/reading-directly-from-an-stdistream-into-an-stdstring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this (bufSize can be modified to fit your needs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void ReadPartially(const char *file)
{
    const unsigned bufSize = 10;
    ifstream is(file);
    string str(bufSize, '\0');
    unsigned count=0;
    while(!is.eof())
    {
        count++;
        is.read(&str[0], bufSize);
        cout << "Chunk " << count << ":[" << endl << str  << "]" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that there's a strong guarantee that `&str[0]` will return a contiguous chunk of memory (at least not in the current standard)...

Comment: You are right. Only the vector class guarantees the continuity of the buffer where data is stored. But in practice I haven't had any problems with string class also. It's good this was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with good old fopen and fread, they give you more control in such situations.